# Background image not covering page on mobile

Tags: css, html, mobile

I've poked around the forums but can't figure out what's going on. I've got a page at food-io.appspot.com that looks great on desktop but on mobile, I can't get the background image to cover the entire space - instead, green bars show up. I've tried some of the suggestions around background-size: cover to no successes and would love to hear any other recommendations!

Thanks,
Eric

Comment: We like code. Give us code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set the `background-size` to `cover` or `contain`?

Answer (score 0):

When you set it to `background-size: cover;` did you also give it a height of 100%?